# agent{docker{}} equivalent command in jenkins scripted pipeline to use docker container as slave agent with label and arguments

Tags: docker, jenkins

In Jenkins scripted pipeline, How we can use all the parameters of agent{docker{}} similar like we have in declarative pipeline ?

```
agent {
      docker {  image 'ansible:latest'  
                label JENKINS_NODE
                args '-u root:root -v /tmp:/tmp'
             } 
}
```

I have tried below code but it's not taking any attributes.

```
node{
    withDockerContainer(args: '-u root:root -v /tmp:/tmp' , image: 'ansible:latest' , label: 'JENKINS_NODE') 
// your build steps 
}
```

Not able to found any specific solution for same. Please suggest.